# ternary operator not working for multiple code

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

So I am trying to color code if a value is either AWOL, Active, or On Leave
I have been looking into ternary since my code is inside an echo already, since the first part checks if there are any users in that slot.
Here is the code that works:

```
<strong> Status: '. ( ($co['status'] = 'AWOL') ? '<j style="color:#CC000A">'. $co['status'] : $co['status']) .'</strong>
```

When I try to add another ? : part is where I run into issues. So something like:

```
<strong> Status: '. ( ($co['status'] == 'AWOL') ? '<j style="color:#CC000A">'. $co['status'] : ($co['status'] == 'Active') ? '<j style="color:#00A808">'. $co['status'] : $co['status']) .'</strong>
```

I end up with errors or everything is green (second color (#00A808)). Also been reading the other not error but problem I am getting, and it says Nested ternary expressions (without parentheses) looking that up doesn't really show me or lead me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: To be honest you're better off avoiding ternaries and using regular if statements.

Comment: This code is hard to read I agree with @JacobMulquin

Comment: Yeah, was trying to avoid that since I am checking if there are any users in the database first to just show the header and having it blank if no one member was a part of a rank. I will prob revert to if statement.

Comment: Simple ternaries are OK, but nested ternaries are overly confusing. PHP 8.0 even requires that you use extra parentheses to make sure that the grouping is what you intend. It looks like you parenthesized it correctly, so I'm not sure why you're getting incorrect results.

Comment: Wrap the last tertiary in parenthesis: `(('firstcheck' == $firstcheck)? 'firsttrue': (('secondcheck' == $secondcheck)? 'secondtrue' :'secondfalse'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this using an array that maps Status => color. This gives you the ability to change the colours easily down the track. Even better would be to have CSS classes instead of inline styles.

```php
<?php

$statuses = ['AWOL', 'Active', 'On Leave'];

$co = ['status' => $statuses[rand(0,count($statuses)-1)]];

$color_map = [
    'AWOL' => '#CC000A',
    'Active' => '#00A808',
    'On Leave' => '#000000'
];

echo '<strong> Status: <j style="color:'.$color_map[$co['status']].'">' . $co['status'] . '</j></strong>';
```

Comment: This is WAY more readable than the nested ternaries

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the [rand]? Since that throws any color on either one of those even if they are active, it will put 'Active' as red or when I refresh will go yellow etc. @JacobMulquin

Comment: @Self_taught_codes The `rand()` is only there for demonstration purposes, I was assuming that in your implementation, you already have the `$co` variable set.